Update open read-only version of shared workbook to show saved changes made on editable version of workbook
There is a workbook in a shared drive.
In computer A, I open the workbook, edit, and save it from time to time.
In computer B, the workbook is open in read-only mode.
I set a macro that runs when the workbook is opened in read-only mode, to reopen the workbook with Workbook.Open every 10 seconds with the OnTime method.
I expect the read-only workbook in computer B to show the changes made in computer A after the editable workbook was saved.
The content of the workbook in computer B didn't change.

So you're calling Workbooks.Open on an already open workbook?

Please edit your question and add the relevant codes.

@BigBen Yes. I've seen other people try to reopen their workbooks like that. Not sure if that is the right way to reopen a workbook.

To reopen, close the workbook first, then call Workbooks.Open.

@VBasic2008 I will. Unfortunately the file is in the company's computer and I can only access it tomorrow. I try to describe my question first as I'd like to see some hints/suggestions asap. If I have time tonight, I might just write the code again then post it here.

@BigBen I've tried that. But since it's the same workbook, once I close it, the code just stop running.

@OTstand A trick for that (which… well, isn't something I'd recommend relying on) is that if you use Application.OnTime to schedule a macro from a Workbook, and subsequently close the Workbook, but not the Application (i.e. Excel remains open), then Excel will reopen the workbook when the scheduled time is reached…  This works even if the Scheduled time is Now() (i.e. no delay)

@Chronocidal Oh...thanks for the input! Always loved to see these tricks and to try it myself.

The Workbook.Open method will open a workbook that is not already open.  Excel will not permit you to open two workbooks with the same name.
What I believe that you want is the Workbook.UpdateFromFile method, which updates a Read-Only file from its source.
So, code to refresh the the workbook if it is Read-Only would look like this:
If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then ThisWorkbook.UpdateFromFile


Thanks for your reply! When the Workbook.Open is executed, I see the monitor refreshes and I guess the workbook is reopened :P didn't heard of Workbook.UpdateFromFile method before, will definitely check it out and do some testing. Will get back to you after I tried it.

From the description of the method, it seems it does exactly what I want though.

Managed to test the Workbook.UpdateFromFile method before I sleep, it worked! Thanks again. Wonder why when I searched sth like “Excel VBA update read only workbook,” I see no one mentioning this method.
